# Maximize and cascade a specific windows desktop program

Tags: powershell

What I want is to take the all the notepad windows in the taskbar that are minimizes or unminimized and maximize them, then cascade the notepads so I can look at them all at one shot and  either make a save or delete decision on each one.

This script below works  - however it maximizes everything and then cascades everything. It neaten ups the desktop - but again I would like to just focus on the many notepads that I have open.

```
(Get-Process | Where {$_.MainWindowTitle}).MainWindowTitle -and {$_.Description -like '*note*'} | % {
    $wshell = (New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell)
    $wshell.AppActivate($_)
    sleep 1
    $wshell.SendKeys("% x")
    sleep 1
    $ShellExp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
    $ShellExp.CascadeWindows()
} | Out-Null
```

Comment: You can use p/invoke to call CascadeWindows to cascade the windows. Resizing them can be done with SetWindowPos.

Comment: Yes that will work  - but how do I just maximize and then cascade just and only just the many notepads that i have open. The above script maximizes everything and cascades everything running on desktop

Comment: Get-process also exposes the windowhandle for each GUI process. It comes down to getting all the window handles for the notepad processes, then run a foreach to resize them with SetWindowPos, then call the Cascade with an array of windowhandles. The win32 CascadeWindows command takes an array if windowhandles as one of its parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do requires multiple, nontrivial P/Invoke calls to the WinAPI:

```bash
# Helper type for various window-related WinAPI functions.
Add-Type -Namespace Util -Name WinApi -MemberDefinition @'
    // The callback delegate, which receives:
    // - the hWnd being enumerated
    // - a custom LPARAM value passed on invocation to EnumWindows()
    // The delegate must return $true to keep enumerating; in other words: $false stops the enumeration.
    // Note the custom ArrayList parameter in lieu of an IntPtr (LPARAM) (using a generic list is NOT an option, because generic types cannot be marshalled).
    public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, System.Collections.ArrayList lParam);

    // The EnumWindows() API function that enumerates *top-level windows*.
    // It too uses a custom ArrayList parameter instead of the IntPtr (LPARAM), which the callback receives.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, System.Collections.ArrayList lParam);
    
    // Get the class name of a window by its handle.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder classNameBuf, int nMaxCount);

    // Cascade the specified window(s).
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern ushort CascadeWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, uint wHow, IntPtr lpRect, uint cKids, IntPtr[] lpKids);
    
    // Show the specified window.
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    // Make the specified window the foreground window, if allowed (see below).
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    // Allow making the windows of other processes the foreground window 
    // for the remainder of the session.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SystemParametersInfo")]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo_Set_UInt32(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, UInt32 pvParam, uint fWinIni);
    public static void AllowWindowActivation()
    {
      if (! SystemParametersInfo_Set_UInt32(0x2001 /* SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT */, 0, 0 /* timeout in secs */, 0 /* non-persistent change */)) {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Unexpected failure calling SystemParametersInfo() with SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT");
      }
    }
    
'@

# Get all Notepad windows, on the assumption that their window class name is 'Notepad'.
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $matchingHwnds = @()
$null = [Util.WinApi]::EnumWindows(
    {                                                                  # delegate (callback function)
      param([intptr] $hWnd, [System.Collections.ArrayList] $param) 
      $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new(1024)
      $null = [Util.WinApi]::GetClassName($hWnd, $sb, $sb.Capacity-1)
      if ($sb.ToString() -eq 'Notepad') {
        $param.Add($hWnd)
      }
      return $true # continue enumerating
    }, 
    $matchingHwnds                                                          # the array list to pass as custom data
)

# Reverse the matching window handles (if any).
[IntPtr[]] $matchingHwndsInReverse = [Linq.Enumerable]::Reverse([IntPtr[]] $matchingHwnds)

# Make sure all windows are restored (non-minimized, non-maximized), in reverse order.
foreach ($hwnd in $matchingHwndsInReverse) {
  $null = [Util.WinAPI]::ShowWindow($hwnd, 1)
}

# Cascade them.
$null = [Util.WinAPI]::CascadeWindows([IntPtr]::Zero, 0, [IntPtr]::Zero, $matchingHwnds.Count, $matchingHwnds)

# Activate them in reverse order.
# First, enable cross-process window activation...
[Util.WinAPI]::AllowWindowActivation()
# ... then activate them.
foreach ($hwnd in $matchingHwndsInReverse) {
  $null = [Util.WinAPI]::SetForegroundWindow($hwnd)
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Shell.Application.CascadeWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-cascadewindows) indeed by design invariably cascades *all* (presumably non-minimized only) windows - you cannot constrain it to only a given application's windows.

  - Additionally, this method seemingly no longer works as of Windows 11; similarly, the cascading feature has been removed from the GUI (you used to be able to right-click on the taskbar and select `Cascade windows`).
- `(Get-Process | Where {$_.MainWindowTitle}).MainWindowTitle -and {$_.Description -like '*note*'}` is *syntactically misconstructed* and effectively results in a single `$true` value being sent through the pipeline.

  - What you presumably meant was this - but it *wouldn't work on Windows 11, with the new, UWP implementation of Notepad*:

    ```bash
    (Get-Process | Where {$_.MainWindowTitle -and $_.Description -like '*note*' }).MainWindowTitle

    # Simpler alternative:
    @((Get-Process notepad).MainWindowTitle) -ne $null
    ```
  - On Windows 11, with the new UWP implementation of Notepad.exe, only the title of a *single* Notepad window - namely the *currently or most recently active* one - is reflected in the `.MainWindowTitle` property of the Notepad processes, so that there's no one-to-one relationship between processes and visible windows.

Therefore, a WinAPI-based solution, as shown above, is required, because it:

- allows you to find top-level windows by *class name*, independently of examining *processes*.
- allows you to cascade only a *given set* of windows (though you must *activate* them separately).